# How to use find command to search strings in filenames in the order that I typed?

Tags: find

Say I'm trying to find a file name that contains the two words `One` and `Two`. The sequence must be in that order e.g.
`./fksklknejnwjOnesvjnh9uibivuwTwojnwovno`.
At the same time, I would want to exclude any files that contain the words in opposite order, like
`./fksklknejnwjTwosvjnh9uibivuwOnejnwovno`.

So far all I got is the following, which does not exclude files with tho words in the wrong order:

```bsh
find . -type f -name "*One*" -name "*Two*"
```

Any help would be appreciated and sorry if this question is very basic. Just a beginner and first time posting here.

Comment: Look for `One` `wildcard` `Two` ... all three in one search term

Answer (score 3):

The `-name` test in `find` uses a common filename globbing pattern.  The pattern `*One*Two*` matches any name that contains the two substrings `One` and `Two` in that order.

Therefore:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*One*Two*'
```

With `-name '*One*' -name '*Two*'` you would find files with names containing both strings, in any order.   Since each individual test is true for files with the words in the "wrong" order, this will give you the files that you want to exclude.